# Error Install apache2-prefork-dev for passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, apache2-module

Hi guys I have the next problem when I go to install apache2-prefork-dev with this command:

**sudo apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev:**

.
.
.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apache2-prefork-dev : Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

Why get I this error?

I am using vmware in windows 7 64 bits.

I have doing:

**sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**

but I get:

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I am using ubuntu Ubuntu 10.10
- the Maverick Meerkat - released in October 2010 and supported until April 2012.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried:
    apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev libaprutil1-dev

Comment: Yes but I get the next message: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libaprutil1-dev : Depends: libapr1-dev (>= 1.2.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

Comment: there is probably a conflicting package already installed on the system. Try adding libapr1-dev to the apt-get install command and keep building the line up until it either succeeds or fails with a different message.

Comment: I have reinstall ubuntu and now working fine in other ubuntu s.o. Thank you veyr much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same issue on server running Ubuntu 10.10. After an hour of trying to install various packages I removed passenger gem and installed it from [Brightbox repos](http://wiki.brightbox.co.uk/docs%3aphusion-passenger).